# Python Codingbat balance_point: How to get started

Tags: python

I have a coding bat challenge that I need to get done and have already searched here for a solution or any other advice and haven't been able to find any.

Here is the challenge:
The "balance point" is point where a list of values array can be split so that the sum of the numbers on one side is equal to the sum of the numbers on the other. (The balance point is included in the "second" sub-list.) Given a non-empty list of ints, return the balance point, or -1, if no balance point exists for the given list.

```
balance_point([1, 1, 1, 2, 1]) → 3
balance_point([2, 1, 1, 2, 1]) → -1
balance_point([10, 10]) → 1
```

I want to separate the list into two parts and sum each individual part, then compare the sums. However, how do I know where to split the list? and how can I sum these numbers from the left and from the right?

any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a coding challenge. So shouldn't you aim to solve the problem yourself...

Comment: Yes, Willem, but I have exhausted all of my resources at school and elsewhere on the internet and am still stuck on getting started. That is the entire reason that I posted on here... very constructive response. Thanks

Comment: In the way of advice, start with what you don't know. Search for "separate list into two parts in python".  Check the python docs (specific to your python version) for lists to see what methods are available that might help you. Second, consider the problem of summing a list as a separate problem and try to solve it.  The docs also have an introduction to python which should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

#### Base case: if the size of the list is less than two return -1

#### Setup

- Let s<sub>R</sub> be the sum of the right sublist, and *R* is the index of the last item in the list *n-1*. Set s<sub>R</sub> to the value of the item at index *n-1*
- Let s<sub>L</sub> be the sum of the left sublist, and *L* is the index of first item in the list *0*. Set s<sub>L</sub> to the value of the item at index *0*

#### Algorithm:

1. **if** s<sub>R</sub> < s<sub>L</sub> ***AND*** *R-1* is greater than *L*, then add the value at index *R-1* to s<sub>R</sub> and set *R* to *R-1*
2. **if** s<sub>L</sub> < s<sub>R</sub> ***AND*** *L+1* is less than *R*, then add the value at index *L+1* to s<sub>L</sub> and set *L* to *L+1*
3. **if** s<sub>L</sub> = s<sub>R</sub> ***AND*** *L+1* is less than *R-1*, set *R* to *R-1* and set *L* to *L+1*, then repeat steps 1-2
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until all conditions are false

#### Answer:

If s<sub>L</sub> = s<sub>R</sub>, return *R*, otherwise return *-1*